# MySQL query not executed while listening for PayPal answer

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

It's already **THREE** hours. I tried EVERYTHING :(
Basically, using some code that I already used in other projects, I wait for a confirmation from PayPal, I get it, and I should store the information in the DB. All the PayPal info is ok and perfectly working.
This is what I tried:

1. Thinking that the DB connection could close itself being idle for some time, I reconnected it and even RECREATED it (at this point, I do not care about memory leaks, performance, etc. etc.)
2. Tried both simple SELECTs and INSERTs
3. Added printouts (to a txt file) every single line, printing all possible errors
4. I print the query in the file and I copy/paste it into Adminer/PHPMyAdmin/HeidiSQL and the query WORKS without any error

The results:

1. I do not get ANY error (all the `mysqli_connect_errno` and `mysqli_error` are ALWAYS empty strings)
2. The DB is not modified at all

This is the part of the code, cleaned of useless checks (that works, anyway):

```
if ($sandbox)   
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
else
  $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
  debug("http error");
} else {
  fputs($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (stripos($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
      if (is_array($data)) {
        $conn->close();
        $conn = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if (!$conn) {
          $err  = "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
          $err .= "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
          $err .= "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;              
          debug("DB ERROR $err");
        }             
        $conn->set_charset('utf8');
        $s = "INSERT INTO sold SET txnid=2";
        debug("trying query $s");
        $sql = $conn->query($s);
        $err = mysqli_error($sql);
        debug("DB result ***$sql*** ***$err***");
        $orderid = $conn->insert_id;
        debug("orderid ***$orderid***");
```

To summarize:

1. There is NO ERROR when (re)connecting to the DB
2. The query `INSERT INTO sold SET txnid=2` runs PERFECTLY if typed by hand
3. `mysqli_error` NEVER gives an error back
4. `$conn->insert_id` is always EMPTY
5. ... but the DB is NEVER updated!
6. As said, I tried to print the result of a simple SELECT (and the result is always empty), I tried to put a debug statement (it simply appends the string to the end of debug.txt) after each and every line, and every line is executed, so there is no syntax error in PHP, ... I am going crazy...
7. It runs on a Ubuntu16.04 VPS with PHP7, and I am not too familiar with the possible differences between PHP5 and PHP7, maybe there is something PHP-related that I am overlooking...

Any idea what is possibly going on?
Sorry for the length but I wanted to show ALL the things I've tried :(
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Where does your `if (is_array($data)) {` closes
?

Comment: several lines down... I didn't want to put the whole source, just the important part. As said, at one point I put a single printout AT EVERY LINE to be sure it was not stopping due to a syntax error in PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it is coming into the if condition below

```
if (stripos($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
  if (is_array($data)) {
   //Put some debug code here and check
```

Hope it might help

Comment: Yes, it goes inside because I SEE all the printouts later in the code

Answer (score 0):

It was a CRAZY sequence of events, but at the end it was (of course :) :) :) my fault.
I defined a SERVER constant in a previous include file, but I used SERVER_NAME in my code.
PHP never gave me an error back because first of all this file was called by PayPal and it was not user-initiated, and second the logs were off.
I enabled the logs, and I saw the error.
The first problem that threw me off was here:

```
$conn = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if (!$conn) {
    // IT NEVER GOES INSIDE HERE IF IT FAILS!!!
```

And then here:

```
$sql = $conn->query($s);
$err = mysqli_error($sql);
debug("DB result ***$sql*** ***$err***");
```

Basically, since `$conn` was not instantiated, all the subsequent calls using it were failing, giving back what I *thought* was an empty string (meaning NO ERRORS), while in fact was either a false or a NULL value.

Lesson learned? Well, keep the PHP log running while developing :)